# VBScript to remove empty rows from csv

Tags: excel, windows, csv, vbscript

I am brand new to VBScripts and trying to use a script I found on SO.  The script will convert an XLSX file to a CSV.  That is working great but the CSV has empty rows and it is causing me some headaches.

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

**How can I modify the above script to remove empty rows before saving as CSV?**

I read this would do it but it does not seem to work and throws a runtime error

```
oBook.UsedRange
```

Comment: `findstr /v /r /c:"^,*$" input.csv > output.csv`

Comment: Does it matter where I put this line?  Can you show me in an answer so I can accept?

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error now, it will help to see your addition using my example

Comment: [`findstr`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732459.aspx) is an external command. Run it in CMD to clean up the CSV file after your VBScript has finished.